# Make text appear after time in application has passed

Tags: java, swing, timer, java-time

i been working on a application using swing as my main library and in brief I want to make text appear in the same lable but in different time interval. Let's say that 5 seconds after the application is running a label will appear an have some text on it. 4 seconds after that the text will change and so on. This is my code right now. I been trying with Java.Swing.Timer but i can't figured out how to make text appear with different Delay.

```
int delayS = 3000;      
      Timer timerS = new Timer( delayS, e -> { 
        switch(cont) {
            case 0: //Change text after 5 seconds
                lblColor1.setText("text here");
                cont;
                break;
            case 1: //Change text 2 seconds after case 0
                lblColor1.setText("and here");
                cont;
            break;
            case 2: //Change text 4 seconds afet case 1
                /*
                lblSorpresa1.setText("and here");
                lblSorpresa1.setVisible(true);
                lblSorpresa1.setBounds(91, 130, 571, 50);
                btnSorpresa1.setVisible(true);
                cont++;
                next = false; // This is for something else 
        }
      } );
      timerS.setRepeats(cont);
      timerS.start();
```

This is what is working for me right now, but the time between cases is 3 seconds.

Comment: Your code sets an original delay of 3 seconds. If you want the delay to change then you use the appropriate method of the Timer class. I believe the method is `setDelay()`. Read the Timer API.

Comment: You have defined `delay` at the top of your code. You could just change that (to 1000, maybe) and then change your switch statement case values to activate appropriately

Comment: @camickr can you tell me more? Should I remove the switch?
In that case I would change all the switch for just the first 'setText()' but where do I put the 'setDelay()'

Comment: *where do I put the 'setDelay()'* - where ever you want to change the default delay. Based on the comments in your code I would suggest the initial delay should be 5 seconds. Then in the case 0 you reset it to 2 seconds and then in case 1 reset it to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple example of what you're looking to do.

Here's the GUI before any text is displayed.

[image: GUI 1]

Here's the first text.

[image: GUI 2]

Here's the second text.

[image: GUI 3]

Here's the final text.

[image: GUI 4]

I created an Object array to hold the text to display and the time in milliseconds to display the text before the next text is displayed.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimedDisplayGUI implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TimedDisplayGUI());
    }
    
    private int textIndex = 0;
    
    private JLabel label;
    
    private Object[][] text = { { "text here", "and here", "and again" },
            { 2000, 4000, 3000 } };
    
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Time Display GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        timer = new Timer(5000, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(16f);
        
        label = new JLabel(" ");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (textIndex >= text[0].length) {
            timer.stop();
            return;
        }
        
        label.setText((String) text[0][textIndex]);
        timer.setDelay((int) text[1][textIndex++]);
    }

}
```